# c++/cli project debug build crashing after installation

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a solution with WPF projects, C# libraries and one C++/CLI project. Installers are built using WiX.

When I install the Release build it all works fine, when I install the Debug build the app crashes with a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyC++CLIComponent.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

When I change the build configuration to use Release for just this component but Debug for the others it works fine.

What would cause the Debug build of the C++/CLI project to fail?

I'm trying to get `AtlTrace` information out of the component after installation but it doesn't output in Release builds.

Comment: You cannot distribute the required msvcrxxx.dll, the DLL that contains the CRT code.  Like msvcr90d.dll for VS2008.  You probably didn't install msvcr90.dll either but you can get lucky with that.  Some user won't be so lucky.  You'll need a setup project, tick "Visual C++ Runtime Libraries" in the prerequisites.

Comment: I have seen this error before with the missing C++ runtimes if that's what you mean? However the WiX installer has the C++ merge modules in its config and it works in the release builds and I see no reason why they'd be excluded from the debug installer builds as there's no conditions associated with them except for a check for $(var.Platform) = 64 to include the 64bit msm.

Comment: If you use the merge modules then you should be fine.  However, you cannot deploy the debug build of your project, the merge modules only deploy the release build of the CRT dlls.  There is no scenario where shipping the debug build of your project is supported.  Or makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks Hans. I'm trying to get ATLTrace output output from an installed application but I believe(d) trace information is only available with debug builds. I wanted to install a debug build on a problem machine to help diagnose problems via trace information. I guess this is not how it happens?